# How rename a .rc file in made Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have been doing some fixes in a project made in MFC/C++ ; I want to know how to rename the .rc file. I will explain more specifically in this picture:

"DbcEditor.rc" is the name that I want to get changed

[image: Editor]

The other question, once the program is running and compiled, the main form has a main title, How could I edit it? I just want to change the text in the form, not the name itself for the object, I will explain it better with the following picture:

"THE CURRENT MAIN FORM" is the text that I want to change:

[image: main form]

Those are my questions, I would really appreciate if you guys could help me with it.

Comment: Go to "Solution Explorer" (Ctrl+Alt+L) right-click on resource file, select "rename". To change dialog caption, there is a field in dialog property called "Caption", change it. ps, this has nothing to do with C++, remove the tag.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer. I have changed succesfully the .rc name for the correct one.

Excuse my ignorance, Could you please telling me where the "dialog property field" is ?? I cannot see it in the Solution Explorer Window @BarmakShemirani

Answer (score 0):

You need the "Properties" windows, see the image below. It's different than Solution explorer.

When you are editing the dialog, click on Dialog's title, then click `F4` button. It should show you "Properties". You can change dialog's caption and other properties. Or you can click on dialog's controls, and edit properties of each control.

[image]

Comment: Mister @Barmak Shemirani, I have done it, in the Resources Viewer I have surfed until the point that I am able to see the windows (let´s call the "forms") I have seen also the Caption feature and now I am able to edit the Text in the very top of this forms. The thing is that the main form is not showed, all of them are there except the main, do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: You didn't seem to have any problem earlier. It wouldn't stop working when you changed the resource name, or when you changed the dialog title. You must have done something else. Start a new MFC project, use "Dialog Based", be careful with the names. By the way, it's just called a dialog, not forms like in .net

Comment: Oh no Sir @Barmak Shemirani ; the software is working just fine, the matter is that the text in the main dialog is still incorrect, with the instructions that you gave me I was able to edit the other dialogs that I have made, but I cannot edit the main one. Besides that, the software works perfectly.

There is a folder named "Dialogs" where I am doing the modifications, in this folder I am not able to find the main one, this one that controls all other dialogs, do you have any idea where could I find it? I know this is my project but, to be honest, I am lost at this point. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's not called "form". It's called dialog. Your main window is a dialog, or it could be a window, with SDI or MDI style --- Anyway, you can change the dialog caption with `SetWindowText`. Look for the *.cpp file associated with your dialog and see if there is `OnInitDialog`. You can start a new question, this time use MFC/C++ tag. Show the relevant code from your *.cpp file.